# Convert SQL Datatime using python

Tags: python, date, time, unix-timestamp

I have a query that returns a date time in sql, example:

```
+---------------------+
| created             |
+---------------------+
| 2008-07-31 21:42:52 |
+---------------------+
```

In my python code I am doing the following to capture the data by calling the query. Here is my python code:

```
query_item_created_f = None
                    query_item_created_f = query_item_created.format(parent_id=question_id)
                    self.dbCursor.execute(query_item_created_f)
                    created_date = self.dbCursor.fetchall()
                    print created_date
```

I get the data and time in following format:

```
({'created': datetime.datetime(2008, 7, 31, 21, 42, 52)},)
```

How can I change this to unix data time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Call the [`.timetuple()` method](http://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.timetuple) on the `datetime.datetime` object, pass that to [`time.mktime()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/time.html#time.mktime) to create a UNIX timestamp:

```
>>> import datetime
>>> dt = datetime.datetime(2008, 7, 31, 21, 42, 52)
>>> import time
>>> time.mktime(dt.timetuple())
1217533372.0
```

Comment: dt = datetime.datetime(int(created_date))
TypeError: int() argument must be a string or a number, not 'tuple I am getting this error, I cast it to int just like this:
                print created_date
                dt = datetime.datetime(int(created_date))
                unix_time = time.mktime(dt.timetuple()

Comment: problem is my date is in following format 2008-07-31 21:42:52 and according to your example I need to separate them to integers.

Comment: No, you showed that your database returns a `datetime.datetime()` object already; in my example I *recreate* the same object so that I can call the `.timetuple()` method on it. You do *not* need to do the same.

Comment: In other words, use `print time.mktime(created_time[0]['created'].timetuple())`

Answer (score 0):

Try with `strftime`:

'`datetime.datetime(2008, 7, 31, 21, 42, 52).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')`

Comment: That's not a [UNIX time value](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time) (seconds since the epoch).

Comment: `seconds since the epoch` the catch `:)`